# How to Test SSRS reports with automation tool

Tags: selenium, reporting-services, webdriver, report

I am testing an asp.net web application which displays a SSRS report using
ReportViewer control. I have searched over internet over last few days but can't find anything. Is there any way to test SSRS report  through Selenium Webdriver or any other tool?

Thanks!

Comment: Little late but what kind of testing you are planning to do?

Comment: I am planning to test the reports having data since the id's are random also I have to click on dimensions to drill down the report in order to test them manually, this i want to automate i can send you the sample report if you want

Comment: We do the same testing but not the content of the ssrs report. we don't want with go that route since it would require some third party tool integration to read the report and will be very hard to maintain.

Comment: Ok, Then want else can I test if not the content of Report

Comment: we test reports load only

Comment: Hi but you can test content as well using selenium without using third party tool to at least 1-2 drill, I just done that but up to 1-2 levels only.

Comment: You are probably not interested any more on this. But found a link that might help you deciding what to do. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94ad0f16-6863-43bb-a5dd-fe903489d0db/data-comparison-of-a-continuously-changing-ssrs-report?forum=vsautotest

Comment: you could also render the report bytes, record the size of a known good report, store that as your base count somewhere (database / resource fie) then if you write some NUnit test daily, just check the current byte size against the known good size. It's not the best test but it's better than not checking any content.

Comment: A byte size would make tests difficult to maintain. Easily maintaining tests is one of the three core concepts of TDD.

Comment: I've created tests on report contents by running the report and exporting it to XML with data and comparing the data with what is expected to be there.  We didn't test every element, but the key ones.